# Django-facebook. How to use a user's profile from other apps(not django-facebook)

Tags: python, django, facebook, facebook-graph-api, django-facebook

I'm new to django. Now I just added django-facebook to my project. The installation went fine, everything seems working.

Now I'm trying to use user's profile like name,facebookID, etc. to other apps beside django-facebook.
I tried to use

from open_facebook import OpenFacebook

```
def create_bets(request):
            graph = OpenFacebook(access_token)
            facebook.set('me/feed', message='check out fashiolista',
         url='http://www.fashiolista.com')
    return render_to_response('createbets.html', args)
```

it doesn't work. I'm getting an error that access_token doesn't exist. Could anyone suggest me a solution please?

Comment: You need to configure access tokens in your settings file, and you must get them from you Facebook API when you create a App within your Facebook account.  It is trying to find the `access_token` and it can't find it.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. You mean I have to create ACCESS_TOKEN in my settings.py. Could you explain or show me some codes of this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use this godjango.com video:

https://godjango.com/13-django-social-auth-101/

It will give you a walk through of how to create social logins using OAuth.  It uses GitHub in the video example.  Within the `django-social-auth` package, you can find out how to install and use it here:

http://django-social-auth.readthedocs.org/en/latest/installing.html

For `Facebook` you need to look in the documentation or the package itself for the name of the access token.  I will give it to you here just in case though.  They are:

`FACEBOOK_APP_ID` and `FACEBOOK_API_SECRET`

In your `settings.py` you can set them up as so using environmental variables:

```
FACEBOOK_APP_ID = os.environ['FACEBOOK_APP_ID']
FACEBOOK_API_SECRET = os.environ['FACEBOOK_API_SECRET']
```

You need to get the actual APP_ID and API_SECRET through your Facebook account. You will want to use the developer Facebook site to create an App and then generate the API credentials.  The web address for this is:

https://developers.facebook.com

Hope this helps.  Put these together and you will have social logins for your web app.